# angularjs2 websocket client

Tags: angularjs, websocket

I have a problem with angularjs2.
 have a  websocket receive component, but when websockt triger by onmessage, I update data from socket , but this property not update into view， component code  like this：

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {WSSocketService} from "./wsSocket.service";

@Component({
   selector: "ws-recv-view",
   templateUrl: "app/ws-receive-view.component.html"
})
export class WsRecvViewComponent{
  private receiveMsg: string;
  private _wsSocket: WSSocketService;

  constructor(_wsSocket: WSSocketService){
    this._wsSocket = _wsSocket;
    this.receiveMsg = this._wsSocket.getRecvMsg();
  }

 showMsg(){
  console.log("update recevie  message handle");
  var ws = this._wsSocket.wsHandle();
  ws.onmessage = function(evt){
  console.log("on  WsRecvViewComponent recevie message: " + evt.data);
  this.receiveMsg = evt.data;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: template like this：    <textarea class="form-control" rows="14" id="interative"
      >{{receiveMsg}}</textarea>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it, `this` is not a components this .the code like this:

`showMsg(){
     console.log("update recevie  message handle");
     var ws = this._wsSocket.wsHandle();
     var that = this;
     ws.onmessage = function(evt){
     console.log("on  WsRecvViewComponent recevie message: " + evt.data);
     that.receiveMsg = evt.data;
    }
 }`